# How to see unique values of a txt file with compared to another txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text-files

I have two txt files that every line is an entry. For instance;

```
    #first txt file

        Jonathan25
        Donald32
        Ethan21
        mjisgoat

    #second txt file

        Ethan21
        leonardo1111
        michalengeloo
        Jonathan25
```

How can I form my code that gives the unique values that **exist in the second txt file** but **do not exist in the first txt file**? Actually, first element of second txt file should be compared to all elements of first txt file. Then, if there is no match, I need to see the value. In this case, what I would like to get as a result is ***"leonardo1111"*** and ***"michalengeloo"***.

Comment: `grep -Fvxf file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: Is this a python or bash question?

Comment: Python would be better actually. I added "bash" or "scripting" tags to see how It can be done with bash as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way in Python would be to read both files into sets, then apply [set difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference). We should also make sure newlines are stripped, to cover cases like `Jonathan25\n` and `Jonathan25`, which should be equal, but won't be if the `\n` is included.

```
with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2:
    s1 = {line.strip() for line in f1}
    s2 = {line.strip() for line in f2}

    print(s2.difference(s1))
```

Output:

```
{'michalengeloo', 'leonardo1111'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the join command in unix.  Have each file sorted.  Then

```
$ join -1 1 -2 1 -v 2 -o 0 file1 file2
```

Or you can use python:
1. create a set.  Cycle through file1 line by line and throw the words into the set.
2. Cycle through file2, and search in the set just created for each word from file2.  Those not found in the set are the word you need to identify.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk: `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !a[$0]' first_txt_file second_txt_files`

Python, use sets: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]
c = filter(lambda x: x not in a, b)
```

in this case, c will only contains 1 element - 5
So you can try to read content of file1 in to a, read content of file2 into b.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way:
set-arithmetic, https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/set-arithmetic/

With set-arithmetic, you can just:

```
$ set-arithmetic --difference second.txt first.txt 
michalengeloo
leonardo1111
```

It's written in Python. It treats each line of the input files as a set element.